# Recommended configuration for Sonar alerts?

Tags: sonarqube

Our project is using [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/) to analyze and measure technical quality. There is an overwhelming range of [metrics](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Metric+definitions) available, along with the possibility to configure visual alerts when metrics drop below a specified threshold.

Are there any decent guidelines available on which Sonar alerts are useful for typical projects, and what threshold values might be sensible?

Answer (score 1):

I can only giva advice according to my own experience. I don't know of any guides / best practises.

I use them to mark undesired states:

1. major code goals I want to achieve (Blockers > 1 --> RED)
2. minor goals I want to achieve (Criticals > 30 --> RED)

I also find it useful to mark metrics, that have been achieved like:

1. code-coverage (Drops under 80% --> RED), architecture tange index < 70% ...

So basically I use the alerts to mark undesired states, to warn if certain metrics fail to achieve a value.

I find the options in sonar very overwhelming, so I picked metrcis that sounded useful or were coherent with current refactoring plans.

I hope this helps a bit :)

Comment: The preconfigured quality profiles do not define any visual alerts. I am looking for guidelines on what alerts others have found to be useful, and what threshold values.

Comment: I read your question differently. Maybe you should take your comment and edit it into the question.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I have edited my question. Hopefully it is more clear now what I am looking for?

Comment: my setup is different for new codebases than existing one : focusing on different aspect of the quality axes http://mestachs.wordpress.com/2012/09/03/why-sonar-rules/